# error code representation using enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have a bunch of error codes being returned to me by the server. Based on these error codes I need to write some logic for each error code. I don't want to place the plain error in my function. What is the best way to represent these error codes?
I am using an enum for now,

```
 private enum LoginErrorCode{

   EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INCORRECT("101"),
   EMAIL_INCORRECT("102");

    private final String code;

    LoginErrorCode(String code){
      this.code=code;
    }

    public String getCode(){
      return code;
    }
  }
```

But I do not know how to handle it if I get an error code unknown to me. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution using your Enum that I typically employ to deal with error codes as you have explained in your scenario:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EnumSample {

    public static enum LoginErrorCode {

        EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INCORRECT("101"), EMAIL_INCORRECT("102"), UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE("---");

        private static Map<String, LoginErrorCode> codeToEnumMap;

        private final String code;

        LoginErrorCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }


        /**
         * Looks up enum based on code.  If code was not registered as enum, it returns UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE
         * @param code
         * @return
         */
        public static LoginErrorCode fromCode(String code) {
            // Keep a hashmap of mapping between code and corresponding enum as a cache.  We need to initialize it only once
            if (codeToEnumMap == null) {
                codeToEnumMap = new HashMap<String, EnumSample.LoginErrorCode>();
                for (LoginErrorCode aEnum : LoginErrorCode.values()) {
                    codeToEnumMap.put(aEnum.getCode(), aEnum);
                }
            }

            LoginErrorCode enumForGivenCode = codeToEnumMap.get(code);
            if (enumForGivenCode == null) {
                enumForGivenCode = UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE;
            }

            return enumForGivenCode;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( LoginErrorCode.fromCode("101")); //Prints EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INCORRECT
        System.out.println( LoginErrorCode.fromCode("102")); //Prints EMAIL_INCORRECT
        System.out.println( LoginErrorCode.fromCode("999")); //Prints UNKWNOWN_ERROR_CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome , but just thinking...isn't using a map etc an overkill? is here a better way to represent these error codes other than enum?

Comment: No, its not overkill.  I use it all the times.  It works great. I have had enums which had around 6 attributes.  I had attributes indicating whether I need to audit a particular error, whether it is system error or business error, etc.  So, go ahead and use it.

Comment: Code I have given above is very generic.  IF you add new enum values, you don't have to change any other code apart from adding your new enum

Answer (score 0):

The point of an `enum` is that there are no invalid values; invalid values do not exist.  There can't be an `LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ERROR_DOES_NOT_EXIST` value.  You shouldn't have to deal with a non-existent value.  That is what makes an `enum` the best representation, because you have a known set of values to represent.

**EDIT**

Since you need to translate the error code strings to your enum, include a `Map` of the error code `Strings` to your enum values:

```
public enum LoginErrorCode
{
    EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INCORRECT,
    EMAIL_INCORRECT;

    private static Map<String, LoginErrorCode> map;
    // static initializer
    static {
        map = new HashMap<String, LoginErrorCode>();
        map.put("101", EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD_INCORRECT);
        map.put("102", EMAIL_INCORRECT);
    }
    public static LoginErrorCode fromCode(String code)
    {
        return map.get(code);
    }
}
```

The `fromCode` method will return `null` on an invalid code.

Comment: Your way is correct, but you need a method fromErrorCode(String errorCode) that return an element of your enum if it is known, and throws an exception or return null if it is unknown. You won't be able to call your enum contructor

Comment: Are you getting the actual `enum` inputted to you, or just the code?

Comment: Awesome , but just thinking...isn't using a map etc an overkill? is here a better way to represent these error codes other than enum?

Comment: It is the best way.  Just translate from `String` to your enum `LoginErrorCode` on the way in, and use your enum internally.